# Cancan Authorizing Controller Action in Nested Resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Using the `load_and_authorize_resource` in CanCan you can choose which actions are authorized by using `:only` or `:except`. i.e. `load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:index, :show]`

I would like to do the same thing in my nested resources but can’t get it to work.

I have a nested resource like:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project
end
```

and have tried to this to restrict the “:click” action:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project, :except => :click
end
```

But this doesn’t work.  Any Ideas how to choose certain actions with nested resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/459).

To skip authorizations for an action on a nested controller `skip_authorize_resource` needs to  be used in the following way.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :project

  skip_authorize_resource :only => :click  
  skip_authorize_resource :project, :only => :click
end
```

The first skip_authorize_resource skips authorization check for task and the second for project. Both are needed if you want to skip all authorization checks for an action.